# How to type return type of redux dispatch

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I have the following code, where `myAction` is a thunk:

```
export type ArgumentTypes<F extends Function> = F extends (
  ...args: infer A
) => any
  ? A
  : never;

const dispatched = <T extends Function>(action: T, args: ArgumentTypes<T>) => {
  const result = store.dispatch(action(args));
  return result;
};

const res = dispatched(myAction, null);
```

how do I correctly type the `ReturnType` of `dispatched` function. `res` is currently showing `any`

Everything else, including `dispatch` is correctly typed.Is there a type in redux that can convert this?

[sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/redux-toolkit-playground-b8bwr8?file=/src/redux/genericDispatcher.ts)

the expected type of `res` in sandbox would be `Promise<string>`

UPDATE:

I was able to get it down to this

```
const dispatched = <T extends AsyncThunk<{}, {}, {}>>(
  action: T,
  args: ArgumentTypes<T>,
) => {
  const result = store.dispatch(action(args));
  return result;
};

const res = await dispatched(myAction, null).unwrap();
```

it now correctly returns whatever is passed into `AsyncThunk<>` but not sure how to make it generic

Comment: We need a [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play#code/Q), please.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/redux-toolkit-playground-b8bwr8?file=/src/redux/genericDispatcher.ts

Comment: Can you clarify _why_ you're trying to write TS types like this?  What are you trying to accomplish overall?

Answer (score 0):

For whatever reason, `<T extends Function>` doesn't work with the built-in types `Parameters<T>` and `ReturnType<T>`.  But `<T extends (...args: any[]) => any>` does work.

I'm a bit confused here as to how you want to accept the arguments of the action creator.  Can there be more than one argument?  Do you pass multiple arguments as separate arguments or as an array?  There's a difference between what you have in your question `dispatched(myAction, null)` and what you have in your sandbox `dispatched(myAction, ["hello world"])`.  In my opinion the `dispatched(myAction, "hello world")` syntax is a lot nicer, so I will do it that way.

```
const dispatched = <T extends (...args: any[]) => any>(
  actionCreator: T,
  ...args: Parameters<T>
) => {
  const action: ReturnType<T> = actionCreator(...args); <-- this intermediate assignment is the key.
  const result = store.dispatch(action);
  return result;
};
```

```
// res has type `AsyncThunkAction<string, string, AsyncThunkConfig>`
const res = dispatched(myAction, "hello world");
```

Comment: the res type is supposed to be a string not AsyncThunkAction

Comment: It doesn't return a `string` though... it returns an `AsyncThunkAction`.  If I console.log it I get: `Promise {<pending>} abort: ƒ abort() {}
requestId: "G7_vEwo5WdtzMCp1Zdura" arg: ["hello world"] unwrap: ƒ unwrap() {}`